# Mismatch between statsmodels and sklearn ridge regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I'm exploring ridge regression. While comparing `statsmodels` and `sklearn`, I found that the two libraries result in different output for ridge regression. Below is an simple example of the difference

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso, Ridge

np.random.seed(142131)

n = 500
d = pd.DataFrame()
d['A'] = np.random.normal(size=n)
d['B'] = d['A'] + np.random.normal(scale=0.25, size=n)
d['C'] = np.random.normal(size=n)
d['D'] = np.random.normal(size=n)
d['intercept'] = 1
d['Y'] = 5 - 2*d['A'] + 1*d['D'] + np.random.normal(size=n)

y = np.asarray(d['Y'])
X = np.asarray(d[['intercept', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']])
```

First, using `sklearn` and `Ridge`:

```py
ridge = Ridge(alpha=1, fit_intercept=True)
ridge.fit(X=np.asarray(d[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]), y=y)
ridge.intercept_, ridge.coef_
```

which outputs `4.99721, -2.00968,  0.03363, -0.02145,  1.02895]`.

Next, `statsmodels` and `OLS.fit_regularized`:

```py
penalty = np.array([0, 1., 1., 1., 1.])
ols = sm.OLS(y, X).fit_regularized(L1_wt=0., alpha=penalty)
ols.params
```

which outputs `[5.01623, -0.69164, -0.63901, 0.00156, 0.55158]`. However, since these both are implementing ridge regression, I would expect them to be the same.

Note, that neither of these penalize the intercept term (already checked that as a possible potential difference). I also don't think this is an error on my part. Specifically, I find both implementations provide the same output for LASSO. Below is a demonstration with the previous data

```py
# sklearn LASSO
lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.5, fit_intercept=True)
lasso.fit(X=np.asarray(d[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]), y=y)
lasso.intercept_, lasso.coef_

# statsmodels LASSO
penalty = np.array([0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
ols = sm.OLS(y, X).fit_regularized(L1_wt=1., alpha=penalty)
ols.params
```

which both output `[5.01465, -1.51832, 0., 0., 0.57799]`.

So my question is why do the estimated coefficients for ridge regression differ across implementations in `sklearn` and `statsmodels`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around a little more, I discovered the answer as to why they differ. The difference is that `sklearn`'s `Ridge` scales the penalty term as `alpha / n` where `n` is the number of observations. `statsmodels` does not apply this scaling of the tuning parameter. You can have the ridge implementations match if you re-scale the penalty for `statsmodels`.

Using my posted example, here is how you would have the output match between the two:

```py
# sklearn 
# NOTE: there is no difference from above
ridge = Ridge(alpha=1, fit_intercept=True)
ridge.fit(X=np.asarray(d[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]), y=y)
ridge.intercept_, ridge.coef_

# statsmodels
# NOTE: going to re-scale the penalties based on n observations
n = X.shape[0]
penalty = np.array([0, 1., 1., 1., 1.]) / n  # scaling penalties
ols = sm.OLS(y, X).fit_regularized(L1_wt=0., alpha=penalty)
ols.params
```

Now both output `[ 4.99721, -2.00968, 0.03363, -0.02145, 1.02895]`.

I am posting this, so if someone else finds them in my situation they can find the answer more easily (since I haven't seen any discussion of this difference before). I'm not sure of the rationale for the re-scaling. It is also odd to me that `Ridge` re-scales the tuning parameter but `Lasso` does not. Looks like important behavior to be aware of. Reading the `sklearn` documentation for [Ridge](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) and [LASSO](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), I did not see the difference in re-scaling behavior for `Ridge` discussed.

Comment: Related query at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/23407